# Transfer of generic constraints

Tags: typescript

Which is better?

```
type Generic<T extends 'some constraints'> = T
type UseGeneric<T extends 'some constraints'> = Generic<T>
```

or

```
type Generic<T> = T extends 'some constraints' ? T : never
type UseGeneric<T> = Generic<T>
```

or a better way I have missed?

Comment: Without more context I can't say which is "better".  Better for what purpose?  Note that `Generic<"some constraints" | 123>` behaves differently in terms of compiler errors and the resultant types, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @jcalz For more elegance. Way 2 needn't to repeat declaration constraints, which is good for use and maintenance.

Comment: "Elegance" is unfortunately subjective (and thus inviting opinions instead of facts).  In addition, since the two snippets in your question have different behavior, the intended use case is probably more relevant than elegance (since elegant code that does not work for the intended purpose is worse than less elegant code that does).  If I asked you "which is better, a pencil or a piece of chalk?", what would your answer be?  Please [edit] the question to specify a particular well-defined use case for which we could evaluate the two snippets.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your suggestion.
I agree that "the intended purpose is worse than less elegant code" at this moment, but pursuit of elegance is always right. Thus, this question is still inconclusive, but I want to keep it.

Comment: So you won't [edit] to include a particular use case?  Then I suppose we are at an impasse and I will disengage.  Good luck to you.